# Why should single space is provided before the format specifier for this given C code?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

In this PROGRAM 1 i am not getting the expected output.

```
// PROGRAM 1
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  char str1, str2;

  printf("Enter char1: \n");
  scanf("%c", str1);

  printf("Enter char2: \n");
  scanf("%c", str2);

  printf("Entered char1: %c\n", str1);
  printf("Entered char2:%c\n", str2);

  return(0);
}
```

In this program i am getting expected output. So pls tell me the reason why not for PROGRAM 1

```
//PROGRAM 2
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  char str1[5], str2[5];

  printf("Enter name: \n");
  scanf("%s", str1);

  printf("Enter your website name: \n");
  scanf("%s", str2);

  printf("Entered Name: %s\n", str1);
  printf("Entered Website:%s\n", str2);

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", str1);` This causes UB.

Comment: And what was your "expected output"?

Comment: As for your problem, I think you need [to read a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) first and foremost.

Comment: "*what is the format specifier for ...*": It's all in the docs: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

Comment: bro in PROGRAM 1 the scanf statement is not asking the input form the user pls help me in this

Comment: @AbdulvakafK please don't edit the question so as to invalidate existing answers.  It's very unhelpful for future users/visitors and annoying for those who gave time to provide answers:(

Comment: I suspect you want `scanf(" %c", &str1);`  (note: & and space)

Comment: Hello https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux 

Exactly i needed "Space" . ok let me know Why(Please explain detail) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` needs a *pointer* as argument. So you should change the `scanf`s in your first program to :

```
scanf("%c", &str1);
```

and

```
scanf("%c", &str2);
```

in order to pass the *addresses* of your variables.

---

The reason why the second program works is that `str1` and `str2` in this case are arrays, so when you pass their names as arguments to `scanf`, you actually pass their addresses. This happens because array names decay to pointers. You can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In first program, `%c` format specifier print only one character. So, if you want to print only one character then use `%c` format specifier.

Also, If you `scan` character type then use `&`. like `scanf("%c",&str2);`

In second program, `%s` format specifier print string. So, if you want to print string then use `%s` format specifier.

`%s` no need to `&` because string buffers are already represented as addresses.

Comment: Didn't you notice the missing `&` in `scnaf` in 1st program.

Comment: I think you should also explain why `&` is *not* needed in the second case.